# Excel adding value to cell throws error

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am using VBA to modify contents of a cell. But the problem is the cell lets say Cell[15,12] is named as "DateCell". When I try to modify the value of this cell using the code -

```
mySheet.Cells(15,12).Value = "09/01/2014"
```

It throws error: Runtime error 1004 -  Application or object error

I have to refer the cell by row and columnn here because i am doing a range of cells starting with this cell. consider this as a range from cell(15,12) to Cell (25,12) and only the first cell is named. all other cells are fine its only this cell which has a name is causing problem.
How to solve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably **Dim** ing or **Set** ing *mySheet* because:

```
Sub hf4uryfh()
    Dim mySheet As Worksheet
    Set mySheet = ActiveSheet
    mySheet.Cells(15, 12).Value = "09/01/2014"
End Sub
```

works just fine